# How to deal with `await` slowing up the operation too much

Tags: node.js, performance, express, async-await, server

I'm writing the registration function in my nodejs server, i'm using mongoose.

this is my function structure currently:

```
function register() {
    password = Password.create(password)
    user = await User.create(userData)
    user.password = password.id;
    token = await createToken()
    await sendEmail(token)
    return res.status(200).send("registered")
}
```

i noticed sending the mail makes the response time x8 higher (from 100ms to 800ms).
now i see a lot of people talking about doing stuff asynchronically and maybe run the "sendEmail" function without the "await".

But really in this case it seems like everything HAS to be asynchronically, because eventually if anything fails here, the user can't really complete his registration, for example if he doesn't get the email then he needs to know that something went wrong and try again, or else he will never be able to verify himself.

so i'm really unsure how to deal with such cases (and specifically this one) where i don't see another choice but to "await" because the user has to know if the operation worked but on the other hand makes the operation 10x slower.

If anybody can give tips/solutions will be very helpful.

Comment: Your title is pretty misleading. The `await` isn't making things slow. The process of sending the email is making things slow.

Comment: I think usually websites don't wait for the verification email to be sent. There is usually a button "I didn't get the email" which allows them to send it again

Comment: It's not your responsibility to _receive_ the email, and your system should send one out if you implemented it correctly. So no, you don't need to `await` the sending of the email in most cases, since you email system won't actually tell you if the email was returned to you as an error anyway. There is nothing you can expect to happen here _but_ for an email to be sent.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder point is to ask what should i do in such cases where i have no choice but to wait for the operation to end but at the same time i want to respond to the user as quickly as possible.

Comment: I'm afraid this is too open-ended and/or opinion-based for SO's Q&A format. There are lots of things you can do, including just assuming the send works and having a means for the user to ask for it to be sent again (in which maybe you'd wait for successful send), or having the operation return a token the front-end can use to then ask for the progress of the process of sending the email, etc.

Comment: @phantttom: One option could be to write to something like a message queue or even just a database table, effectively "scheduling" the email to be sent.  You can return control to the user indicating that a message is being sent.  A separate background application on the server is monitoring that queue and performing the actual task.  It may slow down the overall operation depending on the overall implementation, but focuses on the goal of returning control to the user as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options

1. Even if your internal function thinks the email was delivered, there can always be something that happens with an email. Therefore most websites have button "click here to send email again" and dont wait for any kind of response.
2. You can return some kind of ID of email and have different endpoint which just checks periodically (i.e. each 500ms) if the email si already sent. And then notify user that everything is done and you are just waiting for email verification to finish.
3. You can do similar things with as the above with websockets or realtime database like firebase

In general it is good practice, if any kind of setup/registration process has a lot of inputs and screens, you can quit at any point and then later start from it. Therefore you might let user to fill everything and then wait to verify email. You should be prepared for edge cases when user do not verify email for i.e. 1 month, come back, login, find out he/she must verify email and is able to send verification email again.